# Transform nested array to D3 multiline time series

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to transform a nested JSON object for a time series D3 multiline chart. I'd like to transform this:

```
[
{
    "utc_date": "2012-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
    "data": {
        "view": {
            "count": 9061
        },
        "purchase": {
            "count": 254
        }
    }
},
{
    "utc_date": "2012-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",
    "data": {
        "view": {
            "count": 17232
        },
        "purchase": {
            "count": 539
        }
    }
},
{
    "utc_date": "2012-12-15T00:00:00.000Z",
    "data": {
        "view": {
            "count": 28783
        },
        "purchase": {
            "count": 936
        }
    }
}]
```

to something like this (or better?)

```
[
    {
        "key": "view",
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2012-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 9061
            },
            {
                "date": "2012-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 17232
            },
            {
                "date": "2012-12-15T00:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 28783
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "purchase",
        "data": [
            {
                "date": "2012-12-13T00:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 254
            },
            {
                "date": "2012-12-14T00:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 539
            },
            {
                "date": "2012-12-15T00:00:00.000Z",
                "count": 936
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

To be clear, "view" and "purchase" will not be known and are dynamic. So they shouldn't be hardcoded into the example.

But still wondering if there is any D3.js method or chain of methods to transform this data?

Comment: If a d3.js option does not show up (did you check the docs, right?) you can do this with vanilla javascript, it will take just a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original array is `data`, you could do something like this:

```
V=data.map(function(d){
    w=d.data; 
    M=Array();
    for (e in w) {  // to loop for all parameters
        M.push({"date":d.utc_date, "param":e,"count":w.view.count})
    }
    return M;
})

V=d3.merge(V)

V=d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.param}).entries(V);
```

V will hold your new data structure.

I am sure that this can be further improved.

**EDIT**
Perhaps you don't even need the d3.merge if you only append to another Array to begin with.

```
M=Array();
V=data.map(function(d){
    w=d.data; 
    for (e in w) {
        M.push({"date":d.utc_date, "param":e,"count":w.view.count})
    }
})

V=d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.param}).entries(M);
```

I will let you experiement and see the difference in the performance and code structure.

Hope it helps

Comment: One of the issues is that I won't know what "view" and "purchase" are. In other words they are dynamic. So they could be "click", "delete" etc.

Comment: Ah. ok so it is much more complicated than what is in the example. Can you adjust your question? I'll try and work out my answer.

Comment: Ok, i've update it. I have managed to get a result here http://jsfiddle.net/3umm391n/1/ but not using a d3 method.

Answer (score 0):

Just improving @Nikos answer below to cater for dynamic keys and, although it doesn't use a D3 method chain, this worked:

```
var result = [];
data.forEach(function(d) {
    w = d.data;
    for (var k in w) {
        if (w.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
            result.push({
                "date":d.utc_date,
                "type":k,
                "count":w[k].count
            });
        }
    }
});
```

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/3umm391n/8/